# wp_link_pages() doesnt show next pages

Tags: wordpress

I have index.php, added break page for pagination in gutenberg, wrote wp_link_pages() in index.php after content. The links appeared, but clicking on them not change the content, i still see only first page. Help.

Comment: Please share snippets of your relevant HTML code to help people understand what the problems is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wordpress code reference says:
"Displays page links for paginated posts (i.e. including the nextpage Quicktag one or more times). This tag must be within The Loop." https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/

So you only use

```
<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
```

if you want to split your wordpress page or post into multiple pages. You need to have the

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

quicktag set at least one time.

If this is your goal and you want to edit the way the links are formatted and outputted, you show set some parameters in your arguments array.

So you have to decide first, what you want your links to look like. This a an example from the wordpress code reference, where the links show "next" and "previous", to navigate inside the splitted page/post.

```
<?php
    $args = array (
    'link_before'       => '<span class="page-link">',
    'link_after'        => '</span>',
    'next_or_number'    => 'next',
    'separator'         => ' | ',
    'nextpagelink'      => __( 'Next &raquo', 'textdomain' ),
    'previouspagelink'  => __( '&laquo Previous', 'textdomain' ),
);

wp_link_pages( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: thanks, i fixed this problem, wp_link_pages() redirect me to single.php, how can i use this function in index.php not to be redirected ?

Comment: When you are talking about the index.php, are you talking about your home page? You can use page templates (i.e. page-home.php with Template Name: Home at the top) and set this to your home page in the page attributes of your page edit screen in your backend. your page template should just not include the code, so there will be no page links displayed.

Comment: index.php is my blog page, i want links to be displayed there, but do not want them to redirect me to single.php. I want scroll post on blog page by lazy load or load-more button.

Comment: This is a new question and not related to wp_link_pages. But in short, you have to adjust the output of the loop, get rid of the the_permalink() and display the_content inside the loop. Lazy load and load more buttons are something you should first look in plugins, if you don't have an idea how to achieve this.